# Django updating multiple instance with for loop, causing inconsistent behaviour

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models

I am using Django 1.10 with sqlite db. I am observing inconsistent behaviour while updating few instance of Model using for loop. Sometime no instance is getting updated and sometime only one random instance is getting updated.

Any suggestions please...
 - is there anything I need to put for immediate db write ?
 - Should I need to change DB from sqlite to some other DB ?

Code in views.py for request.POST method looks like this:

```
for p in participant:
  instance = Participant.objects.get(pk=p.pk)
  instance.attribute = event
  instance.save(update_fields=["attribute"])
  print("instance attribute :", str(instance.attribute))

print("\now checking\n")
for p in participant:
  print("instance attribute :" str(p.attribute))
```

Comment: Are you sure each `Participant` object exists for each primary key you are trying to pass? You might want to use a `try` block on your `instance` variable to see if the `Participant` objects exists or not.

Comment: Yes I'm Sure that Participant object exists for each primary key. I can see this from form.POST and also instance attribute is getting updated inside for loop,  which can be seen from print statement. But after for loop ends it is showing different result.